# Is there a .NET Testing framework that can assert a collection contains elements based on an expression?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I'm trying to test that a certain function I'm building will add objects to a collection when supplied with a collection of Ids.

My test looks something like this:

```
var someClass = new SomeClass();
var someIds = new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };

someClass.AddIds(someIds);

Asset.That(someClass.IdsInClass, List.???);
```

The property IdsInClass is actually an IList and for the sake of argument lets say that it looks something like this:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public SomeClass Parent { get; set; }
    //other properties we don't care about for this test
}
```

I want to make sure that all the ids I made in my test are being added to someClass.IdsInClass

What is the best way to do that?

I was thinking maybe an expression would work like so:

```
Assert.That(someClass.IdsInClass, 
    List<SomeOtherClass>.HasAll(x => someIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

But I don't know if anything like that exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Linq's All...

```
Assert.True( someIds.All( id => someClass.IdsInClass.Contains( id ) ) );
```

Comment: Oh now that looks interesting. I've never seen that before. I'll see if I can use that for my unit test, thanks!

Comment: Assert.True(someIds.All(someClass.IdsInClass.Contains));

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated assertion in [Gallio/MbUnit](http://gallio.org) for that specific test case:

```
Assert.ForAll(someIds, id => someClass.IdsInClass.Contains(id));
```

The benefit is that [Gallio](http://gallio.org) tells which particular elements of sequence are failing (if any). That's certainly better than just getting a generic message indicating that the expression evaluated by `Assert.IsTrue` is just not true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ expressions that resolve to a boolean. For example, I write code similar to the following with NUnit tests:

```
List<string> items = ...
Assert.That(items.All(item => item.Contains("x")))
```

Does that help?

Comment: Kind of.  What I want to do, though, is verify that ALL the Guids I have in my list show up in the other collection.  Just having one isn't good enough.

Comment: As BioBuckyBall suggested, you can use the All Linq extension method instead of Any.